# Positioning an element between two fixed elements

Tags: css

I am facing an issue with styling the page.

I have a header fixed to the top and a footer fixed at the bottom.
There is a tabular structure in the middle of the header and the footer. The problem is that the table expands as per the content below the footer. I need to fix the table height between the header and the footer with a scrollbar on the side of the div rather than the scrollbar on the whole page. This should be auto adjustable in different devices (mobile, laptop and desktop).

Thank You

Comment: Might be worth taking a read through this if you haven't done much CSS before - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model

Comment: Thanks for posting your issue here. We appreciate it. But, we could not be able to help you until you post your code. Show us what you have tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

Put the table into a div & give it a height as per your screen size (Example: **height:72vh**) and also give it **overflow-y: auto** and **overflow-x: hidden**. I think this should be the solution of your problem as per your problem description above. 
and also use **media queries** for auto adjustments (**@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {}** for mobile).

If it doesn't help, kindly share the code.

Comment: I tried giving height in terms of vh but it doesn't help much. If I fix it for 1 device (say laptop), it will leave some space in the desktop and will introduce a scrollbar in the ipad.

Answer (score -1):

You have header and footer with fixed position and known heights. So add top and bottom margins to content block. Top and bottom margins should be equal to header and footer heights respectively. These indents will not allow content to get behind fixed blocks.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

header, footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

header {
  top: 0;
}

footer {
  bottom: 0;
}

div {
  margin: 50px auto;
  max-width: 70%;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <h3>Subheader</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Content ends here.</p>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```